# Has HKBH promised an increase in wealth to one who does Torah?

Tags: deuteronomy, ki-tavo, rebuke-tochacha

I was reading the blessings and curses in parshat Ki Savo and came away with the impression that the blessing is on the things that we already have, our lot, rather than being an increase in what we have.

I.e. blessed shall be *your* mixing bowl, the fruit of *your* womb etc.

Am I correct?

Comment: Excellent question. No need to apologize.

Comment: In the story of Eliyahu and the jug of oil, it is clearly understood that although the oil didn’t run out in miraculous fashion, the woman needed to have something to start off with. Hashem doesn’t send blessing out of thin air. So ask these blessings require something to start off with and which will multiply miraculously more than usual. But mixing bowls won’t rain down from heaven and fruits won’t grow from your kitchen table. One needs a field of trees and a bowl and flour to start and then he will see above normal blessings

Comment: @Chatzkel - thanks, I'll think upon this. Blessings :)

Answer (score 3):

Very good! This is an excellent question, and amazing clarity of mind that you spotted that.

It is well known that Hashem requires you to make an effort for your livelihood ([Bereshit 3:19](https://www.sefaria.org/Genesis.3.19?lang=bi&aliyot=0)), and blesses you with what you already have (See [Kings II Chapter 4](https://www.sefaria.org/II_Kings.4?lang=bi) and the "One Woman", and [Sanhedrin 92a](https://www.sefaria.org/Sanhedrin.92a?lang=bi) about requiring bread on your table in order to receive a bracha, this is also discussed in Zohar that a bracha can't come out of thin air but needs something tangible to attach on to so there is no new creation - I'll try to find the source). I believe that you've also stumbled onto more scriptual evidence that this is how the Providence of Blessing works!

You can pray for more money, but if you are limiting Hashem to bless you and your small vessel (a small mixing bowl), then His blessing will also be limited. Generally speaking, the main vessel for receiving blessing is **trust** (Bitochon), according to Chassidus. See this letter from the Rebbe to someone writing to him with fears about livelihood: https://www.chabad.org/therebbe/letters/default_cdo/aid/1866752/jewish/Parnassa.htm

Emuna is the belief that all livelihood and blessing comes only from Hashem. Bitachon is the trust that He will do good by you, and the more of that you have the more good He does. It's hard to understand this from a theological point of view, but certainly we can understand it from a human point of view. Certainly, if we feel that the people we are looking after trust in us, we find more desire and energy to provide for them the very best we can. Surely, this is superior to a "mixing bowl" or other vessel.

If one has ultimate trust that Hashem can make Him a millionaire out of a small mixing bowl, surely this will be considered a very great thing in Heaven and they will certainly be tremendously blessed for showing such trust in their Father in Heaven!

Comment: Some great points @RabbiKaii but I'm not sure this actually addresses the question?

Comment: Thank you. Hmm, I thought it did. What do you think the question is?

Comment: He is talking specifically about the brochos detailed in parshas ki savo. You seem to be talking generally about hishtadlus

Comment: My point was discussing that bracha requires a vessel, and is limited by the vessel, which is what he is wondering is true, based on the pasukim. True, though, the exact meaning of THOSE pasukim I haven't addressed. Hopefully someone will have a better answer. Cheers